# What can cause Actual rep to differ from Shown rep?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, reputation-recalc

If you look at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69742/earlz) you'll see (at this moment) I have 5,404 rep. This I believe was down to 5,390 or so before today. Yet, in my /reputation report it reports me as having

```
-- 2010-05-10 rep +10   = 5094      

** total rep 5094 :)
```

What can make these two numbers differ for the worse? I always thought rep-recalcs led to more rep because of deleted downvotes and such, but not in my case. Why?

Comment: The only way I keep track of those kind of "events" (deleted or moved questions) is by saving regularly the reputation report and, when seeing a difference with my actual rep, by calling a diff tool to see the differences between the current rep report and an older one. Note: it usually leads to *less* rep (between 30 to 200 points, depending on the actual cause). A question moved will cost you rep on the site where it was first published, while making a *rep gain* on the destination site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rep recalcs often lead to less rep due to deleted or migrated questions and answers.

Comment: 300 is a lot of reputation missing between now and March (at least for me). I mean, I'm not complaining but I just think it'd be handy if there was some kinda log to see where it went

Comment: @Earlz: Go to your stats page and sort your questions and answers by recent or newest.  You should be able to see what's been deleted recently.

Comment: how do you tell if it's been deleted without looking through every single one?

Comment: @Earlz: You don't.  :)  Since you're only going back to March, I thought it would only be a few pages back.