# What happened to my reputation?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

What happened to [my reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494543), it is a bit confusing?

Yesterday I was on 1350 rep and when I woke up I saw myself on 980.. What is that?
Secondly, where are records of 2010-11-06 and 2010-11-07, they are missing in that result?

Kindly explain.

```
total votes: 103
-- bonuses   (100)
 2   4076459 (10)
-- 2010-11-02 rep +10   = 111  

 2   4076581 (10)
 2   4076459 (10)
 2   4086748 (10)
 2   4076459 (10)
-- 2010-11-03 rep +40   = 151       
 2   4086086 (10)
 2   4086233 (10)
 2   4096065 (10)
 2   4096035 (10)
 1   4096411 (15)
-- 2010-11-04 rep +55   = 206   

 1   4103594 (15)
 2   4096411 (10)
 2   4103594 (10)
 2   4104009 (10)
 2   4103737 (10)
 1   4104849 (15)
 2   4104849 (10)
 2   4103761 (10)
 2   4096411 (10)
 1   4104984 (15)
 1   4106000 (15)
 1   4105877 (15)
 2   4106000 (10)
 2   4105877 (10)
 2   4106337 (10)
 2   4110166 (10)
 1   4110328 (15)
-- 2010-11-05 rep +200  = 406   

 2   4123255 (10)
 2   4123255 (10)
 3   4122386 (-1)
 2   4123715 (10)
 2   4123255 (10)
-- 2010-11-08 rep +39   = 445  

 1   4123255 (15)
 1   4131280 (15)
 2   4131280 (10)
 1   4132087 (15)
 2   4133736 (10)

-- 2010-11-09 rep +65   = 510   

 2   4103737 (10)
 1   4076409 (15)
 2   4076409 (10)
 2   4142147 (10)
 2   4106337 (10)
 2   4106000 (10)
 2   4105877 (10)
 2   4104849 (10)
 2   4103761 (10)
 1   4142147 (15)
 2   4096035 (10)
 2   4096065 (10)
 2   4086086 (10)
 2   4086233 (10)
 2   4086748 (10)
 2   4142147 (10)
 2   4147712 (10)
 2   4147725 (10)
 2   4147725 (10)
 1   4147725 (15)
 2   4106337 (10)
 2   4147725 (10)
 1   4147712 (15)
-- 2010-11-10 rep +250  = 760   

 2   4096411 (10)
 2   4131932 (10)
 2   4133124 (10)
 2   4147712 (10)
 3   4153756 (-2)
 2   4154636 (10)
 2   4123255 (10)

-- 2010-11-11 rep +58   = 818    

 2   4161784 (10)
 1   4161859 (15)
 2   4161784 (10)
 2   4086086 (10)
 1   4161784 (15)
 2   4162262 (10)
 2   4162354 (10)
 2   4162262 (10)
 2   4113609 (10)
 2   4123402 (10)
 2   4123502 (10)
 2   4123715 (10)

-- 2010-11-12 rep +130  = 948  

-- 2010-11-13 rep 0     = 948   

 2   4171127 (10)
 2   4161660 (10)
 2   4163966 (10)
 2   4162412 (10)
 2   4161859 (10)
 2   4103622 (10)
 2   4094899 (10)
 2   4076617 (10)
 2   4076349 (10)
 2   4076437 (10)
 2   4100090 (10)
 2   4086086 (10)
 2   4147725 (10)
 2   4106337 (10)

-- 2010-11-14 rep +140  = 1088  

** Total rep is 1088 :)
```

Comment: also my last day 150+ reputations  missing too  ='(

Comment: "required tag" means you need at least 1 of those 4 tags, not all 4 of them :)

Comment: You do get a fair number of upvotes after your answer was already marked.  Sometimes several days later and clumped together. That's pretty unusual at SO. Send an email to your friend and colleagues and ask them to stop 'helping'.  It doesn't help.

Comment: @Hans: I would agree that the vote fraud detector is likely kicking in here.

Comment: See also Jeffs explaination about vote fraud at [5K reputation loss in one day. How BIG is that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75032/5k-reputation-loss-in-one-day-how-big-is-that/75034#75034)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably a **recalc** of your reputation.

When the automatic reputation recalc happens, it runs through the entire audit and work out your new correct reputation score.

On Stackoverflow sites, off-topic, subjective/argumentative, migrated out and duplicate questions are cleaned up periodically as part of regular housekeeping. Most of that means deletion, merging in the case of duplicates. Your new reputation is far lower than you expected now probably because of deleted questions/answers you've posted to are no longer "there" to account the reputation for.

You can check the following posts on the primary meta about this issue:

- [What can cause Actual rep to differ from Shown rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49467/what-can-cause-actual-rep-to-differ-from-shown-rep)
- [Why would I lose rep overnight - could it be related to multiple upvotes from a colleague?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56853/why-would-i-lose-rep-overnight-could-it-be-related-to-multiple-upvotes-from-a-c)
- [rep-recalc tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rep-recalc)