# Harmless fun or abuse of the system?

Tags: discussion, abuse

It looks like some friends set up a game amongst themselves to score the most amount of points on StackExchange sites in a short period of time.  We congratulated them on their fine achievement but it seems we were being gamed and even abused.  Perhaps tomorrow they won't be back and I should forget about it.  Should I just let the existing checks and balances do their work?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that they were gaming the system to get the score?  If they just had a friendly competition to gain legitimate reputation then that is **awesome** and we want that sort of thing.

Comment: For example, if you read another post, you'll see the poster earned "Nice Answer" for 12 votes in 20 minutes.  Now that same answer has 7 votes.

Comment: @Daniel - Or the system detected abusive voting patterns and removed upvotes.

Comment: Are their contributions good quality? If so, _mission accomplished_. Links would be appreciated.

Comment: The comment on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90865/how-does-limiting-my-ability-to-gain-reputation-for-upvotes-200-per-24-hours-ac/90871#90871) seems to indicate that people are gaming the system, although it's claimed its "to see who can help the most people". Related questions: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90865/149432), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90856/149432), the first one is interesting because in the comments, the user claims he knows ways around the rep cap.

Comment: @Rick if you are referring to cbroughton - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90865/how-does-limiting-my-ability-to-gain-reputation-for-upvotes-200-per-24-hours-ac/90871#90871  - then he claims to have been doing it in the **awesome** way, legitimately, in which case saying this is "harmless fun" is vastly downplaying the good that it does

Comment: @Daniel: I'm all for healthy competition.  Contributing for one day only is better than not contributing at all.  To each his own.  But to me it seemed to cross a line.

Comment: @Tim: For example, simply by appearing to be overly-enthusiastic, he cooked up a hundred points on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90865/how-does-limiting-my-ability-to-gain-reputation-for-upvotes-200-per-24-hours-ac

Comment: @Rick - Um, not at all.  Those points [were all legit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161808/cbroughton?tab=reputation) (2 q's with 5 votes each, an answer with 2, and a bunch of edits)

Comment: @Renesis: I don't mean they were cheating; I mean they weren't 100% sincere.

Comment: @Tim: Don't forget http://stackoverflow.com/users/747706/cbroughton?tab=reputation .  I don't see anything wrong here.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/747706/cbroughton?tab=stats  I also see nothing wrong here (see Answers)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> it seems we were being gamed and even abused.

[citation required] - Please don't make baseless accusations - of course we want to know of any and all abuse.  You can either flag it for moderator attention, or if it seems widespread, post a message here.  Posting a message with such an accusation without any evidence is very counterproductive.

If they are following the rules then don't worry.  It's like complaining that a few friends decided to race each other in an existing race.  As long as they don't break the race rules, we don't care whether they are competing against each other specifically inside our larger race.

Answer (score 10):

Since this question pertains to me, it seems only right that I should answer it.

This is a friendly game of legitimate play, you'll notice if you scour our answers and questions that we have only contributed legitimate answers, most of which are far beyond the normal "response" to a question that you expect to see as an answer to a simple question.  We go above and beyond and comment our code, explain our answers, and provide additional research and information for users to follow up on the things we've said to help them learn on their own.

It's the ***awesome way*** as you say.

Comment: Just remember [not to vote on friendly accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89940/what-is-done-against-users-collaborating-to-quickly-gain-reputation/89953#89953) (at least, not systematically)

Comment: Please come back after your contest is over.  We need all the help we can get answering questions.

Comment: @Rick Who said the contest ever ends?  There is no set time limit, it's just an added bragging right on top of using a site such as this.

Comment: Race you to Jon Skeet!

Comment: `"We go above and beyond and comment our code, explain our answers, and provide additional research and information for users to follow up on the things we've said to help them learn on their own."` Sirs, truly you are doing it right.

Comment: **"" Doing it the awesome way since May 11, 2011 ""**