# Why do I keep being asked to prove I'm human?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, captcha

I recently changed my computer and since then SO has constantly bugging me to prove I'm a human being every time I post a question or answer. What can I do to get rid of this?

*Edit:* Actually, it seems it's the whole SE. I was shown a captcha when I posted this as well.

Comment: See also [Please tone the captchas back down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110905/please-tone-the-captchas-back-down), although that's marked complete

Comment: Well... are you a human?

Comment: Go back to your directory, Eliza.

Comment: I get this when I post a couple of answers in a row, if it literally get it *every single time* you add a post in any form that's probably some odd behavior though. Not sure of their algorithm but it seems to be based on your post volume over time which seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed this behaviour only happens in these following specific cases:

1. Your IP has changed several times within the last hour of you being logged in (two or more, in my experience).
2. If you have answered more than (three?) quesitons within a five to ten minute period.
3. If your answers or questions within this five to ten minute time are "spam" catchable (ie: trips a filter)
4. If you have made many (small?) edits to a lot of questions, answers, or comments in a short time.

I am not a StackOverflow.SE or SE developer, so of course I don't know what ***actually*** triggers this; but these are the things that make it happen to me.  I don't care really, Aurora 10a2 automatically completes Captchas (which is another problem for another day.)