# Please allow undoing close votes during a grace period

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, review, undo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

So I was churning through [`/review`](https://stackoverflow.com/review) (only 269,920 first questions to go), and I clicked on “close”, “not constructive”, “Vote to Close”.

*(Aside: the new [`/review`](https://stackoverflow.com/review) is great! Now I feel I'm doing my bit to clean the place up, concentrating on my favorite tags, instead of wasting my time slogging through posts that I knew nothing about.)*

Oops, I'd clicked the “close” button just above the title of the question I'd meant to close, instead of the “close” button underneath. So I ended up voting to close a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4641849) which, while not stellar, is perfectly legitimate.

I can easily (and have) voted to close the question I meant to close, but that other, legitimate question is now on the list of questions with pending close votes. Now this wastes the time of the people going through that list in the next four days, and there's a risk that people will blindly follow through with the closing (come on, you know it happens).

Please allow close votes to be undone, at least during a small time window. I know this has been requested and declined before, but the ability to close posts on one big page — which is part of why the new `/review` works — increases the risk of misclicks.

[image: Brought to you by Pony Canyon]

Comment: If you have a *really* good reason a post shouldn't be closed or should be reopened, couldn't you flag the post? If it's a single close vote on a question that otherwise has no close votes it's probably not going to matter.

Comment: Flagging it in this case is the wrong thing to do. One close vote probably won't mean much, but it would be nice to take back the vote...

Answer (score 2):

As such I believe (and I'm sorry if this moves too far out of the bounds of your original question) that there be the ability (perhaps in the dismissal window) to undo your last flag action.  IE: When you flag something for close, merger, or movement; it should probably give you a grace period (5 minutes?) to undo such an action.

**Reasoning:**

1. Humans make mistakes.
2. Mobile devices ; enough said.
3. Keyboard navigation of the flag window can often lead to incorrect selections.