# Reputation discrepancy

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

There is presently an unusually large discrepancy between my SO reputation (11,961) and that shown on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation (11876).

I check this page with some regularity, so this discrepancy is recent.  I cannot think of a reason for an 85 point delta.  Can one of the moderators please tell me what is going on?

Comment: \*sigh\* Do I really need to dig out all the other questions with the answer `Most likely a deleted answer/question`?

Comment: @Bobby, but that's just it, I cannot figure out what was deleted or otherwise changed.

Comment: [And 90 rep is not large...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75032/5k-reputation-loss-in-one-day-how-big-is-that)

Comment: @Bobby I see that the cause there was disciplinary action.  I also cannot think of anything I have done to merit that.

Comment: @Bobby Is there a better way to get support on this issue than posting here?

Comment: That was just an example. Also, why would you want to know? Only a Mod/10k can dig through the deleted stuff and check if something recent is there together with you. Lots of work...

Comment: @Bobby I don't think it is unreasonable to want to know why reputation dropped 85 points.  If the moderators tell me it is not worth their trouble I guess I will have to live with it, but I am hoping they will not.

Comment: Is it really that much work? I assumed moderators could see deleted items on people's profiles.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Yes moderators can see deleted posts on profiles, but we'd have to check **all** the deleted posts to see which ones were deleted most recently to account for this discrepancy. As it's only 90 points it's not really worth the effort.

Comment: @ChrisF are you a diamond moderator? (Pardon my ignorance, I don't know if it would show up here)  Is it any different for them?  Is there any way *I* can manually search for the deleted post without using someone else's time?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I'm a diamond on Programmers, Web Applications and DIY. As far as I know there's no way for a regular user to search for deleted posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through your questions and answers, however I could not find anything deleted *recently* (as in this week) that would fully account for the discrepancy. I'm not sure how often you check `/reputation`, but I don't think it was a 90 point drop all at *once*.

Whatever the combination, such as:

- Rep earned on posts later made CW then deleted recently (not your fault)
- Irregular vote checks  (not your fault)
- The house cleaning we've been doing recently (not your fault)

... it was (not your fault).

Note, I did not check every date on every answer and every question that was deleted, because I just don't have time to do that. However, nothing seems out of the ordinary.

Comment: I appreciate your checking, thank you.  It did seem to happen fairly rapidly, hence my concern.

Comment: The new `review` system has been dredging up all _kinds_ of stuff, so I'm not surprised. But no, it wasn't a sudden (single) 90 point drop. I'm pretty sure you lost it on points you got on posts later converted to CW, then ultimately (and recently) deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Just press the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button at the bottom of the page. This will result in the real reputation value being shown to you on the main page.

The usual sources for such discrepancies are deleted posts. The source wasn't the irregular-voting script as that one would have triggered a recalc automatically.

A moderator could theoretically see deleted posts in your profile, but they can't easily see at which time it was deleted without checking every single deleted post. I personally think it is unreasonable to ask a moderator to spend that effort, though.

Comment: They are not asking how to synch the reputation.

Comment: I am aware of the recalc button.  I didn't realize it would be that much work for a diamond moderator.  I still shall wait for one to decline to help, but as stated in a comment above, I am prepared to live with that.  I had hoped that reputation changes were more transparent to *someone*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The amount of work depends heavily on the number of deleted posts in your profile. A likely explanation is that you asked or answered a question that was subsequently closed and then deleted at some point.

Comment: Okay.  Since I have over 10K rep, is there some way I can search for this deleted post?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, the search options for deleted posts are all mod-only, as far as I know.

Comment: I see.  Is there a method by which I could search manually?  It is not my aim to cause someone else a lot of work, but I really want to know why if it is at all possible, so I am willing to put some work into it.