# Why did my reputation go down?

Tags: support

My rep dropped over 75+ points in less than a minute...WTF ?

I look at my profile and see nothing in today's activity that suggests I lost any points but somehow I did.

Is this an error because its a pretty f'ing lame situation to be in.

Comment: It's only 75 rep. Did you trigger a reputation-recalc at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/reputation? Does the number it reports match your current total?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reputation discrepancy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113060/reputation-discrepancy)

Comment: Probably: a question where you had an accepted answer with 6 upvotes was deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because on November 23, you triggered a rep recalculation (presumably through `/reputation`). This removes rep that you earned on posts that have been migrated or deleted, namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524520/are-there-any-examples-of-implementing-and-effectively-responding-to-a-chaos-mo) (10k or owner only) that was sent to Programmers SE.