# Where has my account gone on Stack Overflow? Is it deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-accounts

I have been a Stack Overflow user for months, had 1000+ reputation, 1 silver badge, and 8 bronze badges. I just logged it few days ago, and it was working fine, but now I can't log in any more.

In the Users Section, I can't find my name, and when I went to recover my account using my OpenID, it said that this ID doesn't exist in the system.

I can't understand what's happening out there. I don't want to lose my account.

This was my account URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/487642/mazhar-karimi

Comment: Surely, you can understand what is happening...

Answer (score 24):

You have *all* IPs in common with this user, as well as statistically anomalous cross-vote patterns:

[5K reputation loss in one day. How BIG is that?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75032/5k-reputation-loss-in-one-day-how-big-is-that)

[What happened to my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70179/what-happened-to-my-reputation)

also, your profile says you are in "U.S.A." (your old, deleted profile said NYC) and yet your IP addresses, all of them, geolocate halfway around the world. Not a single IP you have appeared at is from the US.

I find that... *interesting*.

Answer (score 7):

You can send a mail to team@stackoverflow.com.  They are able to tell what has happened and possibly correct it.